# Http outperformed Http2 ,why, please help me to figure out?

Tags: performance, nginx, http, https

I'm currently conducting performance testing on my NGINX web server container and I'm encountering some unexpected results. My tests show that HTTP performance is outperforming HTTP/2, despite SSL and reuseport being enabled.

Here are the configurations for HTTP:

**nginx.conf:**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    gzip on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**website.conf (vHOST):**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

**Test 1 results for HTTP:**

```
docker run --rm -it ruslanys/wrk -t12 -c400 -d10s http://ip

Running 10s test @ http://ip
  12 threads and 400 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     1.60ms    0.97ms  27.52ms   75.52%
    Req/Sec    20.40k     2.79k  105.77k    96.34%
  2441871 requests in 10.09s, 61.93GB read
Requests/sec: 241889.68
Transfer/sec:      6.13GB
...
```

And here are the configurations for HTTP/2:

**nginx.conf:**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 16;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
thread_pool iopool threads=32 max_queue=65536;
pcre_jit on;
events {
    worker_connections 8000;
    use epoll;

multi_accept on;
accept_mutex off;

}

http {
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    gzip                on;
    keepalive_timeout   5;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 2G;
    http2 on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_min_length  1000;
    gzip_comp_level  7;
    gzip_buffers  16 8k;
    gzip_types    text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/xml application/javascript application/xml+rss text/javascript application/atom+xml application/json image/svg+xml;
    
reset_timedout_connection on;

aio threads;

server_tokens off;
# Open File Cache
open_file_cache          max=4096 inactive=5m;
open_file_cache_valid    5m;
open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
open_file_cache_errors   on;

server_names_hash_max_size 2048;
 server_names_hash_bucket_size 512;
    real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
    
    log_format debugging '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                 '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                 '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" $request_time';

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    include             vhosts/*.conf;
}
```

**website.conf:**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl fastopen=256 deferred reuseport so_keepalive=on ipv6only=on;
    server_name _;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.key;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.crt;
    index index.php index.htm index.html;
    root /var/www/html;

 # Enable session resumption to improve HTTPS performance
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;  # about 40000 sessions
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # Enable OCSP stapling for better privacy and performance
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    # recommended ssl settings for better security
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
}
```

**Test results for HTTP/2:**

```
docker run --rm -it ruslanys/wrk -t12 -c400 -d10s https://ip

Running 10s test @ https://ip
  12 threads and 400 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     3.27ms    1.83ms  46.73ms   72.65%
    Req/Sec    10.12k     0.87k   12.28k    76.58%
  1210716 requests in 10.03s, 30.73GB read
Requests/sec: 120722.60
Transfer/sec:      3.06GB
...
```

**I built the Docker image using the following Dockerfile:**

```
# Base image
FROM debian:bullseye

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        wget \
        libpcre3 \
        libpcre3-dev \
        zlib1g \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libssl-dev

ARG NGINX_VERSION="1.25.1"
ARG CONFIGURE_ARGUMENTS="--prefix=/etc/nginx \
    --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
    --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
    --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
    --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock \
    --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp \
    --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp \
    --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp \
    --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp \
    --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --with-compat \
    --with-file-aio --with-threads  --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module \
    --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module \    --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module \
    --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module \
    --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module \
    --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream \
    --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module \
    --with-stream_ssl_preread_module"

# Download, compile and install Nginx
RUN wget --inet4-only http://nginx.org/download/nginx-$NGINX_VERSION.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzvf nginx-$NGINX_VERSION.tar.gz && \
    cd nginx-$NGINX_VERSION && \
    ./configure $CONFIGURE_ARGUMENTS && \
    make && make install && \
    cd .. && rm -rf nginx-$NGINX_VERSION nginx-$NGINX_VERSION.tar.gz

RUN mkdir -p /var/cache/nginx/client_temp

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 80 443

# Start Nginx
CMD /usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

My server environment consists of Rocky Linux 9.2, Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc, and the Linux kernel version is 6.4.3-1.el9.elrepo.x86_64. The NGINX version is 1.25.1.

Does anyone have suggestions on why I might be seeing these results?

Comment: Have you also measured performance with SSL enabled and HTTP/2 disabled? Your first test skips all the encryption overhead.

Comment: AFAIK HTTP/2 has encryption enabled, comparing that to plain HTTP is no different from comparing HTTPS to HTTP. Of course plain HTTP will win in both comparisons.

Comment: OP cross-posted on SF and got there the same comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1139917/http-outperformed-http2-why-please-help-me-to-figure-out#comment1486566_1139917

Answer (score 0):

HTTP does not have to encrypt the communication as HTTPS does and HTTP/2 should. Therefore, HTTP is faster.